# Why is it a poor approach to build a class by publicly inheriting another class?

Tags: c++, oop, inheritance

I'm studying for my OOP final, and came across a question that has me a bit stumped. The question is "explain why building a Stack class by publicly inheriting a List class is a poor approach. Describe a better solution."

I'm not sure if my answer is right, but is it because of "publicly inheriting..."? And that it would be better to inherit privately instead so that way no class other than Stack would know of the inheritance?

Comment: Aint it because a list allows more operation / random access stuff which is not permitted on a stack ?

Comment: A stack isn't a list (inheritance). It can be implemented using a list. In contrast, private inheritance is composition, so it's better suited for this case.

Comment: I would say more along the lines of lists are sortable, randomly accessible, etc.

Comment: Beat you by 9 seconds :), hehe

Comment: Referring to the title: Who told you so?!? That totally depends on the particular use case, and can't be generalized in that way. Most of my framework classes, if intended to be inherited, **should be** inherited simply `public` (and my OOP fu isn't that bad IMHO).

Comment: @ManuelArwedSchmidt this is not a race, the content and information capacity of the answer still matters

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If a derived class publicly inherits from a base class, the derived class *is* an instance of the base class, potentially with some extra functionality or overridden functionality. In the case of a stack and a list, a stack isn't a list - it logically doesn't perform list operations like searching, concatenating, reversing, etc. - so inheriting from list would not be a good idea.

You could use private inheritance here, but that's not a particularly elegant solution. Instead, you could just implement stack by having it hold a list as a private data member. This is the reason why you often hear "favor composition (having private data members) over inheritance."

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 2):

Private inheritance is *also* a bad idea here. The key point is really that a Stack isn't a List. While you could have a list implementation that only supports stack like operations this doesn't follow from the definition of a list.

In general you should always prefer composition over inheritance. Inheritance should, ideally, only be used to introduce runtime polymorphism. (Inheritance can sometimes be used for convenience, but you should limit this as a much as possible as it creates possibly unnecessary coupling to the base class).

Answer (score 2):

Maybe it's about not using inheritance and take advantage of composition instead.

`Stack` *has* an internal list instead of `Stack` *is* a list (which is false: stack is semantically different than a list).

Answer (score 1):

This is because public inheritance affects interface. If Stack publicly inherits List, it will include List interface.

Yes, private inheritance is better approach there. Personally, I prefer using aggregation in such cases.

Answer (score 1):

Public inheritance

```
class A : public B
```

is used to denote that class A *is* some kind of class B, it extends this class. Since Stack is not a List

```
class Stack : public List
```

is wrong.

> And that it would be better to inherit privately(...)?

Better but more correct IMO would be to implement a Stack by a List as a data member or pointer to implementation.

Answer (score 1):

It is not always true that you should not publicly inherit from another class.  You should certainly not do so if the base class exposes functionality that your inherited class should not provide.  I.e., a class that inherits from another is a specialized type of the base class – which means that all of the base class’ functionality should apply to the inherited class.  The inherited class should add additional functionality, or or provide a specialized/custom form of the base class’ functionality.

In the case of a list vs. a stack, the stack should NOT expose all the functionality that a list provides.

Specifically:  A stack manages a collection of objects by allowing consumers to insert objects into the collection, and remove the last object inserted into the collection. (LIFO).  Typical interface methods for a stack are “push” and “pop”

A list, on the other hand does not have the same limitations.  It alows access to its objects in any order – often by using an index.

If you publicly derive a stack from a list, a caller that has an instance of your stack class will be able to use the base class’ public methods – which would include functionality to access any member of its collection objects, in any order.   Your stack is no longer acting as a stack!!

Answer (score 1):

For example, you can insert in the middle of a list, but you cannot insert in the middle of a stack, but inheriting a stack from a list implies that you can. If anything, list should inherit from stack (although I wouldn't do that in practice either)